# Why is my Serenity Report incorrect?

Tags: java, selenium, report, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I created a Serenity project, with test classes and stories. When I run my tests, in the report there is no problem with the classic tests, but there is 4 testcases in my story. And if one of them fails, for example the second, then in the report the last two testcase will be under the second. What can be the problem?

I tried these versions:

Serenity - 1.4.0 and 1.8.23

Serenity-JBehave - 1.24.0 and 1.35.0

[In the main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBN5o.png)

[If I open the Story reports with the 4 examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzrMK.png)

[In the second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKpym.png)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please read why a [**`screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea`**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Actually this is not a code and not a text completely. The point in the error is the appearance of the report (colors and positions). I cannot write that here.